# maven assembly plugin dependencySet with transitive dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I don't understand how to add part of dependencies to `<dependencySet>` in assembly

for example I have dependency on group:artifact1 and group:artifact2 that both depend on group:artifact0.

I create assembly descriptor that should copy group:artifact2 with all dependencies.

If dependency on group:artifact1 in pom.xml appears before dependency on group:artifact2, I have only group:artifact2 in target dir, but if I change order of dependencies, than I have both artifacts in target dir.

In result I want to have two directories with different set of libraries.

Simple example here

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>                                                                                                                                                                      
    <groupId>com.kudrevatykh.stackoverflow</groupId>                                                                                                                                                        
    <artifactId>assembly-question</artifactId>                                                                                                                                                              
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>                                                                                                                                                                       
    <properties>                                                                                                                                                                                            
        <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>                                                                                                                                                      
    </properties>                                                                                                                                                                                           
    <dependencies>                                                                                                                                                                                          
        <dependency>                                                                                                                                                                                        
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>                                                                                                                                                          
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>                                                                                                                                                             
            <version>${spring.version}</version>                                                                                                                                                            
        </dependency>                                                                                                                                                                                       
        <dependency>                                                                                                                                                                                        
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>                                                                                                                                                          
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>                                                                                                                                                            
            <version>${spring.version}</version>                                                                                                                                                            
        </dependency>                                                                                                                                                                                       
    </dependencies>                                                                                                                                                                                         
    <build>                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        <plugins>                                                                                                                                                                                           
            <plugin>                                                                                                                                                                                        
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>                                                                                                                                              
                <version>2.4</version>                                                                                                                                                                      
                <executions>                                                                                                                                                                                
                    <execution>                                                                                                                                                                             
                        <id>install</id>                                                                                                                                                                    
                        <phase>package</phase>                                                                                                                                                              
                        <goals>                                                                                                                                                                             
                            <goal>single</goal>                                                                                                                                                             
                        </goals>                                                                                                                                                                            
                        <configuration>                                                                                                                                                                     
                            <descriptor>install.xml</descriptor>                                                                                                                                            
                        </configuration>                                                                                                                                                                    
                    </execution>                                                                                                                                                                            
                </executions>                                                                                                                                                                               
            </plugin>                                                                                                                                                                                       
        </plugins>                                                                                                                                                                                          
    </build>                                                                                                                                                                                                
</project>
```

install.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>install</id>                                                                                                                         
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>                                                                                       
    <formats>                                                                                                                                
        <format>dir</format>                                                                                                                 
    </formats>                                                                                                                               
    <dependencySets>                                                                                                                         
        <dependencySet>                                                                                                                      
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>                                                                                   
            <includes>                                                                                                                       
                <include>org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar</include>                                                                       
            </includes>                                                                                                                      
            <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>                                                                            
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>                                                                                             
        </dependencySet>                                                                                                                     
    </dependencySets>                                                                                                                        
</assembly>
```

`mvn --version` output

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 12:44:56+0400)
Maven home: C:\Users\akudrevatykh\bin\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_11, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Users\akudrevatykh\bin\jdk1.7.0_11\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Can you describe in more details what you like to achieve, cause it looks strange to me? Why would you like to create `dir` which will cause a WARNING during your build.

Comment: `dir` is just copied from my original pom, if I change it to `zip` warning disappears, but resulting zip still contains not all dependencies.

Comment: Ok. Than you are aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is old bug opened for maven-assembly plugin https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-357 with similar examples.

Comment: @Vadzim please, be careful when editing. You changed link to something different from original link.

Comment: Sorry. Can't remember anything about that old edit now. But https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-357 matches the question's title too. Shouldn't have been replacing the link anyway.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-357 matches (it's original issue I posted), but https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-873 - does not match and was created later than I created answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should define the dependencies you like to have in your assembly in the pom file as dependencies. This will make sure the order of building is automatically determined by Maven and will be the same all the time.
Furthermore you just need to give the following descriptor like this which will package all the dependencies into a zip file:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

  <id>dist-assembly</id>

  <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

  <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>
          <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
          <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
          <unpack>false</unpack>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Let the transivite dependencies go into different location:

```
<dependencySets>
  <dependencySet>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>${project.groupId}:*</exclude>
      </excludes>
  </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

The `${project.groupId}` excludes the project artifacts. You can repeat this part as often you need them to be copied.

Comment: I don't want all dependencies go to one assembly. I want just part of them go to one place and one to another. but transitive dependencies should be copied twice.

Comment: after edit: and again, it does not work, please, read carefully original post, I don't want _all_ dependencies to one place, I want _part_ of dependencies with all transitive dependency go to one place. If I change `<include>org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar</include>` to `<exclude>org.springframework:spring-aop:jar</exclude>` in original post I have exactly same result - some transitive dependencies missing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create multiple `dependencySet`s, one for each directory you want to create, then use `includes` or `excludes` to control which dependencies go in which directory.

For example, if you wanted `spring-aop` to end up in an `aop` directory and `spring-jdbc` to end up in a `jdbc` directory, you would use the following `dependencySet`s:

```
<dependencySets>

  <dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>aop</outputDirectory>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <includes>
      <include>org.springframework:spring-aop:jar</include>
    </includes>        
  </dependencySet>

  <dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>jdbc</outputDirectory>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <includes>
      <include>org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar</include>
    </includes>
  </dependencySet>

</dependencySets>
```

You'll need to play about to ensure that the correct transitive dependencies are pulled in, maybe by adding additional `include`s, but you get the gist.

Comment: If I create multiply `dependencySets`'s I should describe all transitive dependencies manually. I want to avoid list all transitive dependencies every time.