# Possibility to add more than one outputDirectory in Dependency Set Maven without redundant code

Tags: java, maven

I'm encountering a problem while adding more than one `outputDirectory` location in `dependencySet` of Maven.

I have added 2 dependency sets to resolve this problem. But it uses redundant code just to specify output location. I want to improve it.

```
<dependencySets>
            <dependencySet>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
                <useStrictFiltering>true</useStrictFiltering>
                <outputDirectory>catalina/lib/</outputDirectory>
            </dependencySet>
           <dependencySet>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
                <useStrictFiltering>true</useStrictFiltering>
                <outputDirectory>catalina/lib/endorsed</outputDirectory>
            </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
```

The output is correct but the code is redundant. Is there a way to improve it to be less repetitive?

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem you’re trying to solve? You showed what you did, although that’s not clear as well.

Comment: I want to add more than one <outputDirectory> in a single <dependencySet> tag like :-
<dependencySet>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
                <useStrictFiltering>true</useStrictFiltering>
                <outputDirectory>catalina/lib/</outputDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>catalina/lib/endorsed</outputDirectory>
            </dependencySet>

So that these jars will be available in both of the specified directory. So is it possible to do so or any other way to resolve this problem?

Comment: What is the original problem you are trying to solve? What is the reason you want this?

Comment: Check this link, it may be useful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505886/maven-assembly-plugin-dependencyset-with-transitive-dependencies

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: @JF 
Hello JF.. As you can see redundancy in above code. Only value of <OutputDirectory> tag is diff diff and rest of code is same. So i want to merge OutputDirectory tag of both dependencies in a single dependencySet.

Comment: @MukeshSwami With "original reason" I meant: Why do you want two output directories?